# How can I always keep a view controller in portrait mode?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

This is the easiest way to explain it, keep in mind the view is nested in a Navigation Controller:

1.) App launches and whatever the orientation the device is in, the App is in portrait orientation no matter what. I have the shouldRotate method returning no, so it never rotates.

2.) I click a button, go to another view and turn it to landscape orientation (which is fine)

3.) While in landscape orientation in another view, I hit the "Back" button on the Navigation Controller and it returns me to the view controller I DON'T want rotated in landscape orientation.

What is a good way to consistently keep my main view controller in portrait orientation while coming from a view controller in landscape orientation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your design allows it you might want to simply hide the back button until the app is rotated back to portrait. This would force them to be in the orientation you need when they navigate back.

Comment: I did this, but figured it would be bad design and sort of look like a bug. Maybe grey out the Back button? Not sure but I hope there is a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: The problem is that even if you are able to force the orientation it will still look really bad because the user will be holding the device at the incorrect orientation and it too will look like a bug. I've done this method myself but it was for a full screen video function so it was pretty acceptable as a solution